# .htaccess redirect for alpha , beta and live site

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect with http:://site.com to http://www.site.com but i have alpha and beta site. http://alpha.site.com and http://beta.site.com that do not want to redirect

I am using below code for rewriting without www to www site. But it is also redirecting alpha and beta site to www site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fit:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^alpha\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Write rules for alpha & beta site before your rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule http://www.alphasite.com/ http://www.alphasite.com/
RewriteRule http://www.betasite.com/ http://www.betasite.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```